# Requests get data different from browser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

If I'm trying to download the HTML code of https://www.conrad.ch/de/p/42105-lego-technic-katamaran-2255199.html to parse out the price. But, I'm getting a completely different code than in my browser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_front = requests.get("https://www.conrad.ch/de/p/42105-lego-technic-katamaran-2255199.html").text
front = BeautifulSoup(url_front, "lxml")
front.find("div", id="productPrice").text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

In the browser I find this:
[image: Browser]

In the downloaded code I don't even find the term "price".

Don't know if it has to do with iframes, Javascripts...? I'm not into web development, so I have no idea where I could start to find the error...

Can somebody help?

Comment: The initial requests downloads a basic layout for the website but not the whole content. It's a vue.js app so it probably does some extra ajax request to get the actual product data OR the data is in the response but inside the javascript (and the vue populates the html content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page is rendered using XHR by JavaScript. The good news is you can access the same API as the JavaScript accesses directly.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
}
params = (
    ('apikey', '1Ikv5R4JFlk6MYIFlBAMSgH1cbvzWdzk'),
    ('overrideCalculationSchema', 'GROSS'),
)
data = '{"ns:inputArticleItemList":{"#namespaces":{"ns":"http://www.conrad.de/ccp/basit/service/article/priceandavailabilityservice/api"},"articles":[{"articleID":"2255199","insertCode":"62","checkAvailability":true,"calculatePrice":true,"findExclusions":true}]}}'
j = requests.post('https://api.conrad.ch/price-availability/4/CQ_CH_B2C/facade', headers=headers, params=params, data=data).json()
# Uncomment the next line to see the JSON object
# print(json.dumps(j, indent=4))
price_elem = j['priceAndAvailabilityFacadeResponse']['priceAndAvailability']['price']
print(price_elem['price'], price_elem['currency'])
```

Outputs

```
38.95 CHF
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening the URI in the browser with JavaScript disabled leaves a page which is fairly empty. This is due to JavaScript not 'setting up' the page.

If you are running Linux or Mac with `curl` installed try running this in your terminal:

> `curl https://www.conrad.ch/de/p/42105-lego-technic-katamaran-2255199.html | grep productPrice`

And you will see that the page there does not indeed have the `productPrice` element there upon the request. The way around this is to use `Selenium` (check [the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) out). In simple terms, it acts like a browser and is able to load the page fully and you are then able to query elements that get inserted after the initial page load by the JavaScript on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the data you are looking for is loaded by JavaScript subsequent to the page being loaded. You can get the data then by using a package such as [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which drives your browser (Chrome in this example), as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
try:
    driver.get('https://www.conrad.ch/de/p/42105-lego-technic-katamaran-2255199.html')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id('productPrice') # wait for up to 10 seconds for this id to appear
    front = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    print(front.find("div", id="productPrice").text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
      -26 %
      CHF 52.95
     CHF 38.95
```